# Perforce Connection Timeout Issue

Tags: perl, perforce, connection-timeout

Getting the following error when running some perforce commands (p4 sync, setting altRoot,...) while doing a workspace setup using Perl script:

**Error: SSL receive failed.
read: Connection timed out: Connection timed out**

The issue seems to be majorly coming after p4 sync.

When there is heavy sync that takes 1-2 hrs, and then after that sync, I run any perforce command, then an issue is coming (Connection Timed Out).

Seems some connection break is coming after long sync. Because if I p4 disconnect() after long sync, and create a new connection just after disconnect, then no issue is coming.

**Anyone else ever faced this issue? Does anyone have its solution?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.